# Increase or decrease the list items width as per the condition

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have a list items as shown below

```
<ul>
    <li>One<li>
    <li>One-One<li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Two-Two</li>
</ul>
```

The output can be dynamic once showing two columns and once showing one column
like this

Two Column Scenario

One   | One-One

Two   | Two-Two

One Column Scenario

One

Two

Please help me how do I go about increasing the width and decreasing the width as per the scenario.I am using angular JS with html5 and css3.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Will the order of list elements be same ?

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `display:flex` and `@media` queries. Check below example by resizing the output window.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 40em) {
  li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  li:nth-child(even) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>One-One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Two-Two</li>
</ul>
```